# how to analyze a C header file?

Tags: c, gcc

I want to write a script that analyzes a C header file.
The header contains a few declarations of functions
The scrip needs to understand how many arguments each function has, and what are their types.

can gcc (or other tool) do this?

Comment: Script or C program?

Comment: I think you're looking for a C parser, but whether a C parser can understand anything is a matter of opinion.

Comment: It's best not to ask a new question to circumvent the closure of a previous one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572220/is-it-possible-to-have-gcc-analyze-my-code-and-give-me-info-about-it - To be blunt, it's plain disallowed. This is only a slight variation on the phrasing of the previous one, and just as off-topic

Comment: You can try to compile the file with debug info (`-g` option) and process the debug info using `libdwarf` or by parsing the output of `dwarfdump`

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to how accurate you want to be when parsing a C header file. You could implement the C grammar for a function declaration and be guaranteed to parse it 100% correctly, but it will be a lot of work.

Conversely, a simple regex matcher is the easiest approach, but could have false-positive matches. You can implement a regex parser using C++, python or even other scripting languages such as bash or powershell. I would suggest python as its beginner friendly.

If you don't know what regex is, it's a simple language used to parse strings and extract data from strings. So you could create a regex expression to find the c function declaration then use that expression to pull out all of the arguments. Should be straight forward.

Create a regex expression on https://regex101.com/ and test it against teat strings, then implement that expression in python to do the work.